# how can i load some content from another html file my main html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to add specific content from another HTML page into my main HTML. I am trying using .load by jquery it is work but run just in firefox, I want some method that works in other browsers like chrome.
I have two HTML I want to insert div with id=2 from second html into first HTML to div with id=ok? could you please help me?
main HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="ok"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

second html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="1">one</div>
<div id="2">two</div>
<div id="3">three</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for what is called AJAX. this can be achieve with pure JS or in my opinion more easily with JQuery.

[AJAX Introduction](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)

Comment: Ajax works in all browsers, and even rather early versions. This of course includes all mobile browsers

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ajax call to load the file as text.Then Append the obtained content into required div with jquery wrapper around it.

```
$.ajax({url: "second.html", success: function(result){
        $("#ok").append($(result));
    }});
```

And of course it should be in document ready event

Comment: i am using this <script >
  $(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({url: "second.html", success: function(result){
        $("#ok").append($(result));
    }});
  });
</script> but it is not work. what is my mistake

Comment: what are you getting inside ajax call.please put a console.log and check